# Ephemeral comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments, automation

Having deleted hundreds of "chatty", "not constructive" and "obsolete" comments, it seems there are (roughly) two kinds of comments:

1. *Permanent*, eg "The foo library has been deprecated. Use foo2 instead"
2. *Ephemeral*, eg "I changed the regex to also work with numbers. Try now."

Ephemeral comments have a *temporary* relevance, and once read can be deleted without detracting anything from the post, and should be deleted as they are *no longer relevant* to the post once initially read.

#### Proposal:

When creating comments, have an option to make the comment "temporary", which means that the comment will be automatically deleted (say) 7 days after:

- the last edit on the post the comment belongs to
- the comment is read by the target user, if the comment was addressed (via @user)

#### Benefit:

This could save users/moderators a lot of time flagging/deleting comments like "thanks!", "are you sure?", "I get a compile error", "OK I fixed it, try now" and similar chatty and soon-to-be obsolete content.

Note: The value of "7 days" is entirely arbitrary. 1 month may be better. 1 day may be better still. To be decided.

Comment: Seems appropriate not to leave my comment hanging around then :)

Comment: Aren't all comments supposed to be "ephemeral"?

Comment: I had basically the same idea as you describe above, including having the "ephemeral" comments being automatically deleted after 7 days. However, my terms for the 2 types were "long term" instead of "permanent", & "transient" instead of "ephemeral", but I actually prefer your 2 terms. I also thought of a few other details, but nothing overly significant. Although it's now over 6 years later & quite a few things have changed, since my posting a question would basically duplicate yours, & several others, all of which got at best a fairly luke-warm reception, I don't think I'll bother trying.